# preg_replace for [list][*][/list]

Tags: php, preg-replace

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am using BBcode for my website, but in the text editor I find a problem:

**Ul**

```
[list]
[*]Lorem Ipsum
[/list]
```

**Ol**

```
[list=1]
[*]Lorem Ispum
[/list]
```

I am using this script :

```
$filter = preg_replace("#[[]list[]](.*)[[]/list[]]#","<ul>$1</ul>",$filter);
$filter = preg_replace("#[[]list=([^0-9][]](.*)[[]/list[]]#","<ol start=$1>$2</ul>",$filter);
$filter = preg_replace("#[*](.*)#","<li>$1</li>",$filter);
```

I get a problem with this script - it can't be used because the script `found symbol after [list]` and it can't execute the next statement

```
preg_replace("#[[]list[]]  (.*)  [[]/list[]]#","<ul>$1</ul>",$filter);    
[list]
[*]   Lorem Ipsum --- Stuck In Long Space 
[/list]
```

Comment: Please read up on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Also use the `#s` modifier to have `.*` match newlines. But also consider searching for a readymade bbcode/whatever converter, as your coding attempt has further flaws.

Comment: You may also want to look at the BBCode module: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 1):

Guess you don’t need it anymore, but to give an answer:

- brackets are special characters in regular expressions. When you really mean a bracket, you have to escape it using backslash. So is the star (asterisk).
- you can parse over multiple lines by the `s` modifier
- you will need the `U` (ungreedy) modifier, otherwise multiple blocks in your code will not work. ungreedy means, that beginnings and endings of matches will be looked for in nearest environment, greedy means the algorighm will search for the longest distance.

I think there were the things I changed:

```
$filter = preg_replace("#\[list\](.*)\[/list\]#sU","<ul>$1</ul>",$filter);
$filter = preg_replace("#\[list=([0-9+])\](.*)\[/list\]#sU","<ol start=\"$1\">$2</ul>",$filter);
$filter = preg_replace("#\[\*\](.*)#","<li>$1</li>",$filter);
```